# Choosing donuts of different flavors with flavor requirements

Tags: combinatorics

If I'm going to buy $30$ donuts from $7$ different flavors, I believe there are ${30+7-1 \choose 7-1}$ ways to do this (stars and bars) if we only care about the contents of my bag (not order). What happens when I require $x$ of each flavor? Let's say I need $1$ of each flavor, is the problem just a question of grabbing $30-7\cdot 1=23$ donuts of $7$ flavors?

If so, that would be ${23+7-1 \choose 7-1}={29 \choose 6}$ ways of filling a bag with $30$ donuts from $7$ flavors, requiring at least $1$ of each flavor. Is this correct? If I require $x$ of each flavor, can I generalize this all to:

$${n-k\cdot x + k -1 \choose k-1}$$

Where $n$ is the number of things I want, $k$ is the number of types of things, and $x$ is the minimum amount of each type that I need. Is this correct, or am I miscounting when I simply set aside the required amount of each type?

Comment: What you have is the standard way of handling this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The number of multisets of $n$ items, in $k$ varieties, such that each variety is included at least $x$ times, is indeed $\binom{n-kx+k-1}{k-1}$.